# How to replace comma delimiter with a (|) in a large sql.txt file

Tags: mysql, import, delimiter

I have to import about 25 million records from a 2 gigabyte txt file to MySQL database.

The records are using comma(,) delimiter, The problem is that one column "Address" has commas within data. i.e

```
"John smith", "Engineer", "Street a, city b, 0090"
"Joel Kate" , "programmer", "USA"
```

using an example above, the import script cuts the import as follows

```
"John smith", "Engineer", "Street a,
"Joel Kate" , "programmer", "USA"
```

I need help on how could I replace the real comma delimeters with (|) so that the commas in address remains the same.

NOTE. I have tried to use Java to run a script, but the file is too big. please help.
I am using dbForge to import data.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Notepad++ or the likes and Find and Replace, searching for " ,"  and replacing with (|)

It seems all the commas you want to replace are preceded by an apostrophe and a space and followed by an apostrophe.

Let me know if this works for you or I completely missed the point.

Comment: 2G file is probably too big to be opened by Notepad++. I use Edit Pad Pro, which doesn't try to load entire file into memory. Of course, there are other text editors that would do the trick as well.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful tip. I tried it before but editors could not handle large files. I manages using emEditor, which handles up to 240+ gigs of a text file. Replaced all the required delimiters.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `LOAD DATA INFILE` to import the file?
If so you could use

```
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

in the import. note that is a double quote " surrounded by single quotes '
so anything enclosed in quotes are placed into one field.

So `"Street a, city b, 0090"` would all be saved in one field.

Comment: This is how the data is, has "" around text. But its dbForge that does not to take that into account. Unless there is a hidden trick that I could not find.